# JavaScript syntax for accessing a property of an object from within the object scope

Tags: javascript, object

I have this function:

```
function Entity(textureSrc)
{
    var entity = {

        texture: textureSrc,
        position: { x: 0, y: 0 },
        test: this.texture,

        construct: function()
        {
            alert(this.test);
        }

    }

    return entity;
}
```

And then this test code:

```
var testObject = Entity("Textures/AirTexture.png");
testObject.construct();
```

As a test, I am trying to utilise the value of `entity.texture` when creating a new property for `entity` - I can't quite figure out what the syntax to do this would be.

I've tried:

- `test: this.texture`
- `test: entity.texture`
- `test: texture`

But none of these work; they all result in `undefined`.

Also - is the use of the word `this` within the `construct` method correct for accessing `test` or should this be done differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the "test" line, "this" doesn't exist yet (since you're in the middle of defining it).

It is, however, valid to use this in the construct function because *this* will exist when that function is evaluated (and will point to what you expect it to unless you rebind the function).

Comment: Good info; so what is the *solution* for accessing the value of `texture` when assigning a value to `test` in my example?

Comment: Either use the same source as you used to define texture (textureSrc), or define test once *this* has been defined (for example, in construct() like this.test = this.texture).

Comment: Ah, so there's no way to reference properties until `this` has been defined? Interesting..

Comment: Not that I know of.  Though really there is never any reason to use *this* in the process of defining an object.  (It would be like in C++ if you had a constructor that just did this->a = a; this->b = this->a; Why not just do this->a = a; this->b = a;?)

Comment: True, just used to being able to reference stuff as soon as it has been defined. I'll make a habit of structuring my information differently in JavaScript - thanks for the info!

Comment: No problem.  And there might be a way to do it that I don't know of, though without the this keyword, I have no idea what it would be.  I'm quite curious now since most languages allow the use of this before complete definition.  Going to have to to google the hell out of it now :).

Comment: It's worth noting that, if memory serves me correctly, in martin's answer, you could validly insert a *this.test = this.texture* after the this.position.  That's because *this* is defined before Entity is called (sort of...), and you're modifying it rather than defining it.

Answer (score 1):

As **Corbin** stated - Probably still be a good idea to have a read of one of Johns old posts [Simple "Class" Instantiation](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-class-instantiation/)

Should point you towards a simple and fast method of object creation:

```
function Entity(textureSrc) {

    if ( !(this.instanceof Entity) ) {
        return new Entity(textureSrc)
    }

    this.texture = textureSrc,
    this.position = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    }
}
Entity.prototype = {
    construct: function () {
        alert(this.texture)
    }
}
```

This way you can Entity in the same way you described:

```
var testObject = Entity("Textures/AirTexture.png");
testObject.construct();
```

Comment: *this* is not bound to the function construct. *this*, in that snippet, is bound to the object referenced by entity.  In JavaScript, functions are just another type like int (number) or string (oversimplification).  Saying *this* is bound to *construct* makes no more sense than saying it's bound to *texture*.  Also, it's worth noting that by the definition there, construct will bound bound (or maybe more accurately binded) to *this* not the other way around.

Comment: @corban sorry but you are wrong! this defined inside of the construct is a variable of the function `construct` Javascript functions are not just another type. They have their own scope and using `this` within entity.construct does not reference the object entity.

Comment: Actually, *this* will reference whatever *construct* is bound to.  As it was declared inside of an object literal as a member of the object literal, it is, by default, bound to said object literal, and thus *this* will reference entity.  Do some console.log()'ing if you want :).

Comment: Seriously, believe yourself all you want, but please, do some console.log()'ing first.  (Just to make sure before I posted my previous comment, I've already tested it.)

Comment: I apologize. I just realized what I was doing wrong :) NZ time.

Comment: No problem :).  And sorry if I got a bit combative...  StackOverflow does bad things to me late at night.... haha

Comment: You too... :) I had Entity defined all over the place as I was writing my response - Still a big advocate for the above "class" model :)

Comment: Yeah, I quite like it too.  Decent performance, and succinctly written.  Then again, oddly enough, I find myself using traditional classes less and less frequently when coding JavaScript.

Comment: True... however still useful if constructing lots of objects :)